# Is "journeyed on" meaning a "short trip with intention to come back"?

Tags: genesis, jacob

In Genesis 35:1 (NASB)

> Then God said to Jacob, “Arise, **go up to Bethel and live there**, and make an altar there to God, who appeared to you when you fled from your brother Esau.”

Then in Genesis 35:16,17

> **Then they journeyed on from Bethel** ... **Jacob came to his father Isaac at Mamre of Kiriath-arba (that is, Hebron)**, where Abraham and Isaac had resided.

Is this "journeyed on" conveying the point that Jacob followed God's command to live in Bethel and was just traveling for a limited short period of time to Hebron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb נָסַע (nasa) simply means to pull up and move or journey forward.  There is no suggestion in the verb itself as to how long the journey will last.

This verb is used often (146 times) in the OT in places like: Gen 11;2, 12:9, 13:11, 20:1, 33;12, 17, 35:5, 16, 17, 46;1, Ex 12:37, 14:10, 15, 19, 15:22, etc.

The Hebrew idiom is of one pulling up tent pegs in  preparation for travelling forward.  The verb carries no overtones of return, only journeying.